# What does Index: -1 say? java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 9

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a code that crashes and gives the following message:
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 9

What does Index -1 mean?

Comment: `index` : the index you tried to access `size` the actual size.

Comment: Index -1 means you passed -1 as the index to an array. How about you show the code that causes this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, your index variable is getting a negative value. Could you please provide some code?

Comment: It is on "Vehicle vehicle = occasionMarket.get(model).remove(index);" that the code crashes.  

`public static Vehicle buyOccasionCar(String model, int index)`
 `{`
  `d_occasionSales++;`
  `Vehicle vehicle = occasionMarket.get(model).remove(index);`
  `vehicle.resetPurchaseTick();`
  `registered_vehicles.put(vehicle.getModel(),` `registered_vehicles.get(vehicle.getModel())+1);`
  `return vehicle;`
 }

Comment: You should check if you index has proper value before making any operation with array or list. So before executing: `occasionMarket.get(model).remove(index);` you should check if  'index >= 0 && index < occasionMarket.get(model).length`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am really new at this! 
How do I check the index?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the array/ list etc you are using have total size of 9 items. But you are trying to get a record/item with index "-1". Because in most languages, array/list indexes start from "0" to "size - 1", so you can't use index either smaller than 0, or greater than size of array/list